# How to have two divs side-by-side with their backgrounds spanning full width, but their content contained inside a wrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[Example image of what I'm trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GZs7.png)

I am trying to set up two divs side-by-side that are flexed. Where there background spans full width and the content is contained within a wrap.

```
<div class="flex-grid">
    <div class="flex-child">
        <p class="flex-child__content">content goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child">
        <p class="flex-child__content">content goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So flex-grid would be display:flex and the flex-child divs would be flexed to be 50%. The flex-child__content would then be in a container, for example:

```
wrap { width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

What is the best way this can be done?

Comment: You could wrap your flex code with a div that takes 100% width of the viewport and give it a gradient background-color. First 50% would have color A and 51-100% color B. Style dummy (paste in your colors): http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1e5799+0,1e5799+50,00cc00+51,00cc00+100 change to horizontal gradient after calling the link

Comment: Just wanted to know if my solution works for you - in case you had time to check.

Answer (score 1):

You could use flex-grid, you assign spaces on a grid that each div will fill, you can get fancy with it.

```css
.flex-grid {
  background: #f00;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 512px 512px auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "space1 left right space2";
}
.flex-child {
  text-align:center;
}
.space1, #left {
  background: #0f0;
}
.space2, #right {
  background: #00f;
}
.space1 {
  grid-area: space1;
}
.space2 {
  grid-area: space2;
}
#left {
  grid-area: left;
}
#right {
  grid-area: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="space1"></div>
    <div class="flex-child" id="left">
        <p class="flex-child__content">content goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child" id="right">
        <p class="flex-child__content">content goes here</p>
    </div>
  <div class="space2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want something like this? You seemed to be pretty much there already.

```css
div {
height: 50px;
background-color: gray;
}
.flex-grid {
display: flex;
}
.flex-child{
width:50%;
text-align: right;
background-color: red;
}
.flex-child:nth-child(2) {
text-align: left;
background-color: blue;
}
.flex-child__content {
display: inline-block;
background-color: transparent;
width: 50%;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
    <div class="flex-child">
        <div class="flex-child__content">content goes here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child">
        <div class="flex-child__content">content goes here</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Sort of, but still not exact. That just cuts the content to 50% of the flex-child, but that doesn't make it follow the rule of the wrap/container. Trying to make it so the contents width lines up with the wrap.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by wrap?

Comment: Sorry, when I say wrap I mean like a container div. So something like: wrap{ width: 1030px; margin: 0 auto; } A div that keeps everything contained and centered.

Answer (score 0):

I borrowed a bit css from @wassona, cleaned it up a bit and added my suggestion.
Hope it works for you. In case you want the two boxes below each other on small devices add mediaqueries - set .bg-wrap background to none and set a bgcolor for each box (they are going to take the whole width in that case)

```css
.bg-wrap {
 background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #253343 0%, #253343 50%, #406375 50.01%, #406375 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #253343 0%,#253343 50%,#406375 50.01%,#406375 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #253343 0%,#253343 50%,#406375 50.01%,#406375 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#253343', endColorstr='#406375',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.wrap {
 width: 1030px;
 max-width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.flex-grid {
 display: flex;
}
.flex-child{
 width: 100%;
 
}
.flex-child__content {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: transparent;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.headline {
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-wrap">
 <div class="wrap">
  <div class="flex-grid">
   <div class="flex-child">
    <div class="flex-child__content">
     <h2 class="headline">STUDENTS, PARENTS,<br>and TEACHERS</h2>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="flex-child">
    <div class="flex-child__content">
     <h2 class="headline">BUSINESS OWNERS<br>and EMPLOYEES</h2>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```